# How do I remove an element from a page using jquery if another div exists upon page load

Tags: jquery

If free shipping appears I want the flat rate div to disappear upon page load.

**Current HTML:**

```
<dl class="shipment-methods">
    <dd>Free Shipping</dd>
        <dt style="margin-bottom: 5px;">

        <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" class="validate-one-required-by-name" value="freeshipping_freeshipping" id="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping">
        <label for="s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping"><!--<b>Free Shipping:</b>--> Free                                <strong>

        <span class="price">£0.00</span>                                                                </strong>
        </label>
    </dt>
    <dd>Flat Rate</dd>
    <dt style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" class="validate-one-required-by-name" value="flatrate_flatrate" id="s_method_flatrate_flatrate">
        <label for="s_method_flatrate_flatrate"><!--<b>Flat Rate:</b>--> Fixed                                <strong>

        <span class="price">£9.95</span>                                                                </strong>
        </label>
    </dt>
</dl>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8T96/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W8T96/1/)***

```
if ($('#s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping').length) {
    var parentDt = $('#s_method_flatrate_flatrate').parent('dt');
    parentDt.hide();
    parentDt.prev('dd').hide();
};
```

check for the existence of freeshipping `id` using its `length` & hide others.

Comment: Tried adding this to the header, it seems not to work however I can see it working in the jsfiddle. `if <script>if ($('#s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping').length) {
    var parentDt = $('#s_method_flatrate_flatrate').parent('dt');
    parentDt.hide();
    parentDt.prev('dd').hide();
};</script>`

Comment: @user2478101 - don't write the script in the head. write it in the `body` with script tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
if($('#s_method_freeshipping_freeshipping').length) {
    $('#s_method_flatrate_flatrate').closest('dt').hide().prev().hide();
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W8T96/3/)**